# Select top n after data operations SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

I want to

1. Filter a data set
2. Take distinct of a column
3. take out top 10 rows of that data set with the distinct column

The code I am using is

```
SELECT TOP (10) * 
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT(business_id) FROM businessdata 
     WHERE businessdata.city = 'Phoenix'
)
;
```

and the error I am getting is

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a name to the subquery:

```
SELECT TOP (10) * 
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT(business_id) FROM businessdata 
     WHERE businessdata.city = 'Phoenix'
) AS my_subquery
ORDER BY businessdata
;
```

make sure you also an ORDER BY to correctly set the order and thus make TOP meaningful